# Mac Illustrator CC > Save for Web > Convert to sRGB… checked & greyed out

Tags: mac, osx-yosemite, adobe-illustrator, color-profiles, adobe-creative-cloud

i've been following some advice from several blogs to normalize the color settings across my adobe apps - basically setting them to none or generic or monitor etc (since i only design for web, really).

one thing they say to do is to make sure the "Convert to sRGB" option is **UNchecked** in the *Save for Web* dialog box in both Photoshop & Illustrator.

well, that's doable in Photoshop, **but it's checked & greyed out in Illustrator (see attached screenshot).** for the life of me i can't figure out how to change that.

more info...
the reason i want to UNcheck this option that's greyed out is to try & get colors to not just *look* correct, but to *match* between Illustrator, Photoshop, & any web browser (Safari, Chrome, Firefox, etc).

currently, i can open up both Photoshop & Illustrator on the screen, side-by-side > create a new 'web' document in both > draw a square > and fill it with a color in one, then do the same in the other with the exact same HEX & RGB color numbers, **and they LOOK different!**

Furthermore, when i use a color-picker on that same square... *it fills in different numbers than what i had originally typed in!*

so i've been doing research > google'ing & searching the Adobe forums,
several Stack_______ sites, & the Apple forums. all i've been able to
find of substance is to make these settings in both Photoshop &
Illustrator - to not manage color profiles nor view profiles for any
psd's & ai's for web-based screen-only designs.

even more info...
i'm on a 6 month old *(mid-2014)* MacBook Pro *(15"
Retina w/a 1 TB SSD & 16 GB of RAM)*; 'had' Adobe CS6 on it. then in
February i *UNinstalled* that & started a new Adobe **CC**
subscription *(downloaded & installed fresh copies of its various
apps, including Photoshop & Illustrator)*.

THANKS for your time & efforts!

> PS: yes, i also posted this @ https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1812587

also...

> PS2: i posted this in the GraphicDesign Stack but it was put on hold'n'closed by the moderators with the excuse that it is "Off Topic" for that stack @ https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/51104/mac-illustrator-cc-save-for-web-convert-to-srgb-checked-greyed-out

also...

> PS3: i don't have enough "reputation" in this particular stack to embed images (as i've done in the GraphicDesign stack post linked above) so here's a link to the screenshot (in case it'd be helpful for anyone to "see") @
>   https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/95838/illustrator-SFW-issue.png
>
> **@Karan**, if you see this & don't mind doing what you did on another post of mine recently, i'd appreciate it - you went ahead & embedded my screenshot (see PS3 above) for the one @ superuser.com/questions/901716/mac-microsoft-word-2011-changes-shape-color-against-my-will